# What is correct tire air pressure for my impala 2005 replaced tire?

Tags: impala, tire-pressure

[image: Tire]

I bought a 2005 Chevrolet Impala which came with custom wheels and tires put on by the previous owner. In the tire sidewall there is printed "49PSI." Is that the right amount of pressure to put in?

Comment: The pressure listed on the tire would be max pressure. I would start with the pressure listed on the A-pillar/driver's door label as the minimum, increasing for comfort and driveability but not to exceed 49.

Comment: Those are very low profile tires, I would think that with so little room to absorb bumps that tire pressure would be critical. I'd suggest asking at a tire store if you can find one, or start near the top of the tire pressure range. The pressure on the A-pillar label will be for the stock tires and I wouldn't trust it with these tires (unless the label clearly seems to apply to the new tires). You might also be able to get an idea by measuring the current pressure in the tires.